# Django Crispy Forms, Bootstrap, helper.label_class and helper.field_class not working

Tags: css, django, forms

I have a problem with the crispy forms framework, setting the field_class and label_class attributes is not making a difference to the layout. I am using Bootstrap3, and all of the css files can be used elsewhere on my site (ie they are being picked up successfully in the static directory).

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_class  = 'form-horizontal'
    helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
    helper.field_class = 'col-lg-10'
    helper.layout = Layout(
        'username',
        'password',
        Submit('submit', 'Log Me In', css_class='btn btn-success'),
    )
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

Upon inspecting element in my browser, the `col-lg-2` and `col-lg-10` CSS classes are simply NOT being applied to the labels and fields respectively...

Comment: Are either of the form_class or the layout attributes being applied? Edit: Also check out changing this setting in your project. http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#make-crispy-forms-fail-loud

Comment: debug option is not showing any error. Can you clarify what you mean by the form_class or layout attributes?

Comment: Is there the "form-horizontal" class on the form element in the HTML that's rendered?

Comment: yes there is. absolutely.

Comment: FYI I am using bootstrap3 for css.

Comment: What version of crispy forms are you using?

Comment: Well I was running 1.4.0, but I just cloned 1.5.0 from the git repo, and there is no change.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton, I'm currently experiencing the same issue, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I had the same issue and this SO post provided the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849485/django-crispy-forms-form-class-appears-but-label-class-and-field-class-does-not

Answer (score 1):

You should place all the helper logic under the `__init__` method:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class  = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-10'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'username',
            'password',
            Submit('submit', 'Log Me In', css_class='btn btn-success'),
        )
```